# Python not matching regexp

Tags: python, regex

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'(.*)\\\\(.*)\\\\(.*)')
>>> m = re.match(pattern, 'string1\string2\string3')
>>> m
>>> 
>>> m.groups
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

I am trying to match strings with the following format in the regexp above: `string1\string2\string3`.

Above is Python's output. Why is it not returning the appropriate regexp object? Is there anything wrong with my pattern?

Comment: As a side note, you probably wanted `pattern.match(s)`, not `re.match(pattern, s)`. You only need the latter if you're using an (uncompiled) string as the pattern. This does happen to work, but it's not documented to.

Comment: More importantly: `re.match` does not return a regexp object. It returns either a match object (type `_sre.SRE_Match` in CPython 2.7) if there was a match, or `None` if there was not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in your pattern, you use `\\\\`, which represents two raw backslashes, while in the text to be matched, you use `\s`, which is actually no backslashes at all (it's a `\s` character).

First, you probably want to make your text a raw string, otherwise Python reads it as the `\s` character.

```
re.match(pattern, r'string1\string2\string3')
```

Second, you need only two consecutive slashes in your pattern, to represent that one backslash:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(.*)\\(.*)\\(.*)')
```

Finally, rather than `m.groups`, you want to do `m.groups()` (call the method). Thus, all together your code would look like:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(.*)\\(.*)\\(.*)')
m = re.match(pattern, r'string1\string2\string3')
m.groups()
# ('string1', 'string2', 'string3')
```

Comment: Thanks! How would you convert a variable that contains a string into a literal string though?

Comment: The first part is wrong. `'\s'` is two characters, a backslash and an s. Try this: `r'\s' == '\s'`. And that makes @Darksky's question irrelevant. (The second part is the right answer here.)

Comment: I am not typing out the string. It's a variable that's passed in that contains the string so I believe my question is relevant: a variable with a string is a plain string and not a raw string. I'm using the second part. How would I raw-ify that string to be used? Or avoid using raw strings all together in this case?

Comment: Python string is different from C/C++/JavaScript that it preserves the ``\`` if an escape sequence is not formed. Those other languages will evaporate the ``\`` if valid escape sequence is not formed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to escape backslashes inside a raw string. From the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals),

> When an 'r' or 'R' prefix is present, a character following a backslash is included in the string without change, and all backslashes are left in the string.

This means that all 8 backslashes stay in your regex, and each pair matches a single backslash in your test string. The problem is immediately apparent [when you visualize it](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=%28.%2A%29%5C%5C%5C%5C%28.%2A%29%5C%5C%5C%5C%28.%2A%29&str=string1%5Cstring2%5Cstring3) (drag the slider above the test string). It can be fixed by replacing your regex with

```
r'(.*)\\(.*)\\(.*)'
```